# error in my search linked list implementation

Tags: c, file, search, linked-list

My program doesn't seem to be opening the text files properly.
I have a path.txt which is a string representation of all the paths of folders and text files which I have created. When running the program however, it will not output the LINES of the text file the user asked for.

OUTPUT

```
enter text file
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
a1.txt
```

IT should have output

```
This is a1
```

text of a1.txt:

```
This is a1
```

text file: path.txt/ this is how my folder is set up with the text files.

```
a/a1.txt
a/a2.txt
a/b/b3.txt
a/b/b4.txt
a/c/c4.txt
a/c/c5.txt
a/c/d/d6.txt
a/c/d/g
a/c/d/h
a/c/e/i/i7.txt
a/c/f/j/k/k8.txt
```

code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct sMyPath{
        char *element;
        struct sMyPath *next;
} tMyPath;


int main(void)
{
        FILE *pFile;
        pFile = fopen("path.txt", "r");
        char inputstr[1024];
        tMyPath *curr, *first = NULL, *last = NULL;

//get the text file, and put it into a string inputstr

        if (pFile != NULL)
        {
                while(!feof(pFile))
                {
                        fgets(inputstr, sizeof(inputstr), pFile);
                }
        fclose(pFile);
        }
        else
        {
                printf("Could not open the file.\n");
        }
```

//using tokens to get each piece of the string
//seperate directories and text files, put it into a link list

```
char *token = strtok(inputstr, "/");
while (token != NULL)
{
if(last == NULL){
        //creating node for directory
        first = last = malloc (sizeof (*first));
        first -> element = strdup (token);
        first -> next = NULL;
} else {
        last -> next = malloc (sizeof (*last));
        last = last -> next;
        last -> element = strdup (token);
        last -> next = NULL;
}
token = strtok(NULL, "/");
}
```

//ask user for txt file

```
char pathU[20];
printf("enter text file\n");
gets(pathU);
```

//check if text file exist, if yes output entires in text file, else say no

```
   while(first != NULL)
    {
            if(first -> element == pathU)
            {
                    FILE *nFile;
                    char texxt[300];
                    nFile = fopen(pathU, "r");
                    while (!feof(nFile))
                    {
                            fgets(texxt, 300, nFile);
                            printf("%s", texxt);
                    }

            }

            else if(first == NULL)
            {
                    printf("invalid file name\n");
            }

            else
            {
            first = first -> next;
            }

}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand two possible requirement/implementation.

1) By your implementation, every link-node will contain just filename and directory name and **NOT THE PATH-NAME**. If you need to store entire pathname, use **'\n'** as delimiter.

```
char *token = strtok(inputstr, "\n");
```

and

```
token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
```

This assumes, when your input is **a/a1.txt**, your current directory contains the directory **a** and which in-turn contains the file **a1.txt**.

2) Otherwise, your existing code expects **a1.txt** to be in current directory, though it  contradicts the input file content.

---

Either way, this below code is culprit,

```
if(first -> element == pathU)
```

which compares the pointer and not the string. Replace it as,

```
 if( strcmp( first -> element, pathU ) == 0 )
```

*I could help better solution if your requirement is more clear..*

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the string comparison: `first -> element == pathU`. Here you are comparing pointers, not the characters of the strings. Use `strcmp` instead: `if (strcmp(first -> element, pathU) == 0) ...`